# mongoimport runs sucessfuly but the database is empty

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoimport

when I import a database with `mongoimport --db Meteo --collection meteo --file meteo.json` it finishes without problems, but when I list databases, it shows that Meteo has 0.000GB. But what is more strange, few days ago it worked fine, and I could import databases and use them normally, but now they are empty too.

Comment: The database with few collections and very little data can still show as 0.000 GB. Did you list the collections in the database? Is the collection created? If so, did you query the collection? What was the message when you ran the `mongoimport`? Was there as error message? Also, try this syntax: `mongoimport --db=users --collection=contacts --file=contacts.json`

Comment: I did list collections and it is created, but upon query it shows nothing. There was no error message after `mongoiport`, but after importing the database with suggested syntax it worked(thank you). Now I am confused because few days ago the syntax that I mentioned in the post worked normally. What changed?

Comment: The syntax I had provided is from the official documentation's example. It is generally safe to follow those.